# Python for loop incomplete

Tags: python

I am trying to convert all csv files in a folder to XML but having issues, code as follows:

```
import glob
import csv

fileCount = 0

path = "csvs\*.csv"
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print(fname)

for fname in glob.glob(path):
    csvFile = fname
    xmlFile = "csvs\myData" + str(fileCount) + ".xml"
    print (xmlFile)
    print (csvFile)
    print (fileCount)
    fileCount +=1
    csvData = csv.reader(open(csvFile))
    xmlData = open(xmlFile, 'w')
    xmlData.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' + "\n")
    # there must be only one top-level tag
    xmlData.write('<userforms>' + "\n")

rowNum = 0
for row in csvData:
    if rowNum == 0:
        tags = row
        # replace spaces w/ underscores in tag names
        for i in range(len(tags)):
            tags[i] = tags[i].replace(' ', ' ')
    else: 
        xmlData.write('<userform>' + "\n")
        for i in range(len(tags)):
            xmlData.write('<response>' + "\n" + '  <field>' + tags[i] + '</field>' + "\n" + '  <value>' + row[i] + '</value>'+ "\n" + '</response>' + "\n")
        xmlData.write('</userform>' + "\n")

    rowNum +=1

#print (fileCount)   
#print (xmlFile)
#print (csvFile) 

xmlData.write('</userforms>' + "\n")
#xmlData.write('</csv_data>' + "\n")
xmlData.close()
```

There are 4 csv files in the original folder, the content of each is the same but the names are `1.csv`, `2.csv`, `3.csv` and `4.csv`. This code does generate 4 xml files but the first three are incomplete with just the xml header created.

Is there abyway to add a delay/check to a for loop to ensure it completes?

Console output is clean with only print info available:

```
csvs\myData0.xml
csvs\1.csv
0
csvs\myData1.xml
csvs\2.csv
1
csvs\myData2.xml
csvs\3.csv
2
csvs\myData3.xml
csvs\4.csv
3
```

Comment: The third for-loop and some code around it must be in (not after) the second.

Comment: The last part of your code, from `rowNum = 0`, must be indented in order to be in the main loop

Comment: Indent your last 14 lines of code by 4 spaces.

Comment: That's it, school boy error. Thanks for you help